# ¿Como acceder a objetos dentro de objetos en javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Trabajo en laravel 5.7 y estoy integrando vue.js.
Tengo un modelo `Property` y otro llamado `PropertyType`, un campo de `Property` (en la base de datos) es el `property_type_id`, con lo que tengo acceso a este objeto mediante su id, en php normalmente accederia haciendo uso de un metodo que fue creado en el modelo `Property`:

```
public function propertyType() {
    return $this->belongsTo(PropertyType::class, 'property_type_id');
}
```

Con esto, al momento de llamarla donde la necesite solo debo hacer:

```
$property->propertyType->name;
```

Sin embargo, no se como se deberia hacer en javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias opciones puedes utilizar la sintaxis del punto o por índice asociativo, puedes leer más acerca de los objetos [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos), cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
var objeto = {

 auto: {marca: 'Audi', modelo: '73', colo: 'rojo'}


}

console.log(objeto.auto.marca);
console.log(objeto['auto']['marca']);
```